# Why is the interrupt not working as intended on STM32?

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32, microcontroller

I am trying to make a simple program that utilizes an external interrupt that controls which of the 2 LEDs will blink. Both LEDs can blink in the absence of the interrupt routine so the configuration of the LED pins (PB and PC13) are correct.
The program is whenever I am trying to use the ISR.
I am using Keil uVision 5 with only CMSIS core for the STM32F103C8 MCU.

In the code below, neither of the two LEDs are blinking.
I am trying to setup the pin PB5 as input Pullup and detect the falling edge as an interrupt when I connect PB5 with GND.

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"                  // Device header

void delay(int rep);
void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler();

// global variable
int signal = 0; // this will change upon each interrupt

int main(void)
{
    // set RCC for PortC to enable the clock BUS
    RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<4);
    // set RCC for portB to enable the clock bus
    RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<3);
    
    // set the mode and function of PC13 to output
    GPIOC->CRH &= 0xFF0FFFFF;   // reset to all zeros
    GPIOC->CRH |= 0x00200000;   // make output push-pull
    
    // set the mode and function of PB3 as output
    GPIOB->CRH &= 0xFFFFFFF0;   // reset to all zeros
    GPIOB->CRH |= 0x00000002; // make output push-pull
    
    // set PB5 as input to later make it an external interrupt
    GPIOB->CRL &= 0xFF0FFFFF;   // reset to all zeros
    GPIOB->CRL |= 0x00800000;   // make input pullup/pulldown
    GPIOB->ODR |= (1<<5); // pullup
    
    // configure PB5 as external interrupt
    __disable_irq();    // disable interrupt requests (for safety)
    AFIO->EXTICR[1] = 0x00000010;
    EXTI->IMR |= (1<<5);
    EXTI->FTSR |= (1<<5);   // set to falling edge
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI9_5_IRQn);
    __enable_irq(); // enable the interrupt requests again 
    
    
    
    // toggle PC13 indefinitely (waiting for interrupts)
    while(1)
    {
        if(signal==0)
        {
            GPIOC->ODR |= (1<<13);
            delay(10);
            GPIOC->ODR &= ~(1<<13);
            delay(5);
        }
        else if(signal==1)
        {
            GPIOB->ODR |= (1<<8);
            delay(10);
            GPIOB->ODR &= ~(1<<8);
            delay(5);
        }
    }
        
}



// ISR Function to service PB5 external interrupts
void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler()
{
    EXTI->PR |=(1<<5);
    if(signal ==1) signal = 0;
    else signal = 1;
}



/// Random time delay Function
void delay(int rep)
{
    for(;rep>0;rep--)
    {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i< 100000;i++)
    {}
    }
}
```

Comment: magic numbers. Use CMSIS definitions to make it readable for humans

Comment: I am honestly still learning the basics following a Youtube video where he does something like this and I decided to make something of my own.

Comment: do not learn from yt

Comment: Where should I learn?

Comment: From books and documetations

Comment: `delay()` function is useless, compiler may optimize it out. Shouldn't `signal` be `volatile`? First check if interrupt handler is called at all.

Comment: Regarding how to roll out register access code yourself without any libs, this might be helpful: [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290)

Comment: @dimich is correct, those are two obvious bugs. Also if `GPIOB->ODR |= (1<<5); // pullup` is the pull up enable register, why are you writing to that one in the main for loop instead of the actual GPIO register? That would be a third bug.

Comment: @Lundin - ODR = Output Data Register.  The comment is unhelpful.

Comment: @Clifford The OP thinks they are setting up a pullup register by writing `GPIOB->ODR |= (1<<5);`.

Comment: @Lundin  Yes, just looked at the code rather then just your comment!  Clearly the register is incorrect.

Comment: @Clifford As is the implementation of the delay function and the missing volatile of the variable shared with an ISR. Feel free to add all of it to your posted answer for completeness.

Comment: those are perfect numbers for human readability right from the documentation.  magic names are not human readable.   and require ten times more work to match with the manual

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The EXTI feature requires the SYSCFG/AFIO to be enabled in the RCC.  Your EXTI configuration will be ignored otherwise.  For STM32F1xx it is the AFIO, other series use SYSCFG.

```
RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<0);  // Enable AFIO CLOCK
```

The initialisation:

```
GPIOB->ODR |= (1<<5); // pullup
```

writes to the wrong register. You intended:

```
GPIOB->PUPDR |= (1<<5); // pullup
```

if the comment is to make any sense.

The delay loop is seriously flawed - at the very least you should have:

```
volatile int i ;
```

Other than that consider using the Cortex-M SYSCLK and `SystemCoreClock` to implement a more plausible and deterministic delay.  For example:

```
volatile uint32_t tick = 0 ;
  
void SysTick_Handler(void)  
{
    tick++ ;
}

void delayms( uint32_t millisec )
{
    static bool init = false ;
    if( !init )
    {
        SysTick_Config( SystemCoreClock / 1000 ) ;
        init = true ;
    }

    uint32_t start = tick ;
    while( tick - start < millisec ) ;
}
```

Any variable shared between thread contexts must also be declared `volatile`:

```
volatile int signal = 0; // this will change upon each interrupt
```

And `signal` need not be tested twice, `else if(signal==1)` can be simply `else`.  That would be better since `signal` may change between the two tests, and end up with neither block being executed.  Never retest a shared variable in the same iteration.  If you need to do that, take a copy at one point and test the copy.